# XAMPP: Changing content of PHP-file doesn't change what's shown in browser

Tags: php, html

First I had this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>PHP file</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        <?php
            echo "Hi again...";
        ?>
    </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I accessed the file through localhost/learningphp/myfirstfile.php and it rendered properly, showing me a h1 element with the text "Hi again...".

Then I changed to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>PHP file</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <?php
            echo "Hi again...";
            $myName = "Sahand";
            echo $myName;
        ?>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice the change of `<h1>` tags to `<p>` tags, and the addition of `myName`. Still, when I go to localhost/learningphp/myfirstfile.php `myName` (Sahand) is not added to the page, and "Hi again..." is still shown in "h1 styling", like when I viewed the first version of the php file. Why is this and what can I do about it?

Comment: Try the following: Restart xampp, restart browser, reload without cache (ctrl-f5 on firefox), because that seems like it works

Comment: Also be sure you saved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have two issues in this case may be

1. You are saving the file somewhere else or you didn't save the
   updated content.
2. Your Browser history try a hard refresh by using `Ctrl+F5` (for windows) Keys
   together

Comment: You're right, I accidentally saved the file somewhere else. My bad. Thanks!